# Drupal 7 Bartik plus theme drop down menu

Tags: theming, navigation

This is actually, must be easy question, ive been fiddling around for some hours trying to figure it out.

The short version is I am making a drop down menu in Bartik,

I am aware of superfish,nicemenues,megamenues, But I am not interested in these.
Since Bartik runs with superfish built in.

I came across this [Drupal 7 Bartik Plus Theme](http://deltup.org/download.php?view.6)
with a fresh install of Drupal

But this menu isnt working. The default menu is not showing.

as you can see here this is how it supose to work

[Drupal 7 Bartik Plus example](http://ourladysmaronite.org/calendar)

Any good ideas to how I get it to work?.

Comment: Is your menu block set properly in the menu block space for bartik?

Comment: What do you mean menu block space, I have edited the block to stay in header region

Comment: Goto Structure > Block. Do you see a block called Main Menu or Menu? Assign it to the Menu block space. This is just one thing to check as sometimes you may want to assign a specific menu to the "main menu" block space..

Comment: Im only seeing the main menu block, I cant see the block just called "menu"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I found was here [Changing Bartik theme to dropdown](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2769/how-to-replace-the-bartik-default-menu-with-superfish)

and I used this CSS file with fixed issue

[CSS file to put into superfish folder](http://drupal.org/node/1073298)

Answer (score 0):

I've just updated that thread with simpler code, resulting in menus that actually look just like Bartik's. Please vote [my answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2769/how-to-replace-the-bartik-default-menu-with-superfish/107356#107356) up if it works for you. Thanks.